# How to get URL of a file in an HTTP GET request?

Tags: download, http, video-streaming, url

There's a web server that I access regularly by making an HTTP GET request like so: `http://www.example.com/index.php?file=12&hd=0`

It returns an `OK` response with a content type of `video/x-flv` and various content lengths. Obviously this downloads a `.flv` file, and since I'm downloading it, it must be hosted on the web somewhere.

However, I cannot figure out how to retrieve the *direct* URL of this file. I've tried using Wireshark and Fiddler4, but they don't help. I'm trying to get the URL so I can use it on [Sync Video](https://sync-video.com), which can accept direct URLs to video files. Trying a link like the example above doesn't work though.

Comment: can you include a screenshot of what you see in wireshark?  By the way, a URL is not part of a GET request (perhaps with a proxy i'm not sure, but proxy aside). a GET request mentions the file and path, and maybe parameters..  You should see that in wireshsark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any other way of accessing the file. The PHP script probably just reads a private local file and redirects the data to the output stream.

This is probably done to prevent hotlinking. Because the PHP script has to be called in order to download the file, it can check certain things (for example if you're logged in) before streaming the data to the client.

If the script doesn't check anything (or only checks your IP address) and the program just denies the URL because it has no extension, you could try faking it:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?file=12&hd=0&ext=.flv
```

By adding a dummy argument to the URL that makes it end in `.flv` the program might accept the URL.

Answer (score 0):

There is not necessarily a method for directly accessing the file.

It may well reside on a webserver in a private folder, or it may reside on an entirely different server that only the web server has access to. The url posted may be the only public method of accessing the file.

Unless you see a 301 or 302 redirect in your wireshark capture, then there isn't any way of interogating the webserver to find out where it gets the file from.